# Migrating to Xcode 10.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, testflight, xcode10.2

I have my iOS project which builds successfully in Xcode 10 but when I tried to upload the application on test flight I am not able to upload. It gives an error -

> From March 2019 onwards AppStore connect will only accept builds from
>   Xcode 10.1 or later and iOS SDK 12.1 and later

.

So I imported the project in Xcode 10.2. There are many libraries used in the project. As I imported the project in Xcode 10.2 I got errors as the libraries do not support updated Xcode version. So I the updated the pod. Still, I am getting the same error.

Is there any solution to this?

Before updating the libraries, they were supporting Swift 3.

Now I have updated and the current version is 4.2.

I resolved all the errors which came due to update if libraries but I am getting errors in Code due to library update.

Comment: The fastest temporary solution for projects with Swift 3 code is to use Xcode 10.1 until you've migrated all your code to Swift 4+.

Comment: You are getting errors in code because these libraries would have deprecated some of the method and you might be consuming it.All you have to do is see the alternative methods for the deprecated methods and use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run the SDK's (Pods) on the comfortable versions of swift as they supported. So just follow the steps below.

1. select your pod space.
2. select the SDK.
3. Go into build settings.
4. change the Swift Version. (As pod supported.)

Do it for all the pod SDK and try to build the project.

Comment: Yes I did that also.

Answer (score 0):

If all you swift related pods and code is upgraded to Swift 4.2.

Then you can compile that with xcode 10.1/

You can download and install xcode 10.1 from [here](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_10.1/Xcode_10.1.xip)

you may very well upload using xcode 10.1 as well.